# Fitting multiple independent values with an exponential equation in one plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, scipy, curve-fitting

I have been trying to fit a curve with multiple independent values.

For a single plot, I am able to plot but for multiple values, I am stuck.

This is my data set:

I have dataset in csv files,

You can find csv here:
https://github.com/Laudarisd/csv_data

This is my code for single plot:

```
# fit a line to the economic data
from numpy import sin
from numpy import sqrt
from numpy import arange
from pandas import read_csv
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from matplotlib import pyplot
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv
from numpy import savetxt
from numpy import asarray

# define the fitting function
def func(x, a, c):
    return  a - 1/2 * np.exp(-(x - 1)/c)

csv = np.genfromtxt ('./10.csv', delimiter=",")

x = csv[1:,1]
y = csv[1:,-1]
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y)
r2 = round((1 - sum((func(x, *popt) - y) ** 2) / sum((y - np.mean(y)) ** 2)),4)
print("R^2:", r2)
a, c = popt

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y, 'ko', label="Raw data")
plt.plot(x, func(x, *popt), 'r-', alpha=.60, label="Fitted Curve")
plt.plot(x, y, color='none', label= "c = %.2f" % c)
plt.xlabel("x label")
plt.ylabel("y label")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

In detail:

1. csv has 3 columns, but I only need 2 columns (Second and third) while fitting curve.
2. Based on second columns I am trying to fit third column with an equation mentioned in above code
3. In all csv, second column is same. which I used for 'x label' and third column(accuracy) is different which I used for 'y label'.
4. So I want to extract all accuracy separately and fit the curves based on `def fun(x, a, c)` in a single plot.

So I will have a single plot with :

- 10.csv - fitting curve
- 20.csv - fitting curve
- 30.csv - fitting curve
- 40.csv - fitting curve
- 50.csv - fitting curve

I hope problem is cleared.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Are you trying to achieve this?

```
# fit a line to the economic data
from numpy import sin
from numpy import sqrt
from numpy import arange
from pandas import read_csv
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from matplotlib import pyplot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv
from numpy import savetxt
from numpy import asarray


colors_list = ["black", "green", "red", "purple", "blue"]
types = ['ko', 'go', 'ro', 'mo', 'bo']
# define the fitting function
def func(x, a, c):
    return  a - 1/2 * np.exp(-(x - 1)/c)

plt.figure()
for i, v in enumerate(["10", "20", "30", "40", "50"]):
  csv = np.genfromtxt ('./'+v+'.csv', delimiter=",")

  x = csv[1:,1]
  y = csv[1:,-1]
  popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y)
  r2 = round((1 - sum((func(x, *popt) - y) ** 2) / sum((y - np.mean(y)) ** 2)),4)
  print("R^2:", r2)
  a, c = popt

  
  plt.plot(x, y, types[i], label="Raw data_"+v)
  plt.plot(x, func(x, *popt), 'r-', alpha=.60, label="Fitted Curve_" + v, color=colors_list[i])
  plt.plot(x, y, color='none', label= "c = %.2f" % c)

plt.xlabel("x label")
plt.ylabel("y label")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi Suleman, Thanks for you time and answer. I was trying to get this. One more thing, is it possible to to insert 'label' inside of box instead of of outside with large box. like  for each line ` color , line name and c = value`, I think c value will be printed automatically.

Comment: Kindly review the updated answer, is this helpful ?